# Прерывание функции

Tags: javascript

Интересует, есть ли возможность в JS (возможно уже готовыми средствами jQ) прерывание выполнения функции аля `return` извне? К примеру, при использовании `foo()` внутри `wtf()`, выполнение будет `wtf()` будет прекращаться.

Comment: На самом деле вопрос так и остается абстрактным - возникла просто мысль можно ли так сделать. Какого-то простого решения не нашел. Мало того, я не исключаю, что этим вообще не стоит заниматься.

Comment: В PHP элементарно. Кстати, пока думал как реализовать в PHP, придумал как это сделать в JS xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Готового решения, лично я, не знаю. В jQ такого точно нет.

Написать подобный функционал самому не является проблемой. Если вы не смогли этого сделать то, скорее всего, вам это не нужно и вы просто поплыли не в том направлении. Уточните в вопросе - зачем это вам, без абстрактного бессмысленного примера с `foo()`, `wtf()`.

Этим действительно не стоит заниматься.
PS: а вы знаете язык где это сделать легко? В JS я вижу код, как, например, реализовать подобное в php, java etc. - вообще не представляю (чтобы удобно юзать было, во всяком случае).